# Electron Squirrel.Windows: How can I remove local app data on uninstall?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, squirrel.windows

Currently I have an installer built with Squirrel.Windows. On uninstall, the application directory under:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\MyApplicationDirectory
```

remains. I have tried using [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) under the the `--squirrel-uninstall` hook to remove the directory, but it fails because the files are in use.

Here is what I have that is not working:

```
case '--squirrel-uninstall':
    var myLocalAppData = "C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\MyApplication";
    rimraf(myLocalAppData);
    app.quit();
```

I have tried the following to no avail:

1. Using a `setTimeout()` to delay the `rimraf(myLocalAppData)` call
2. Using the `maxBusyTries` param in the rimraf options to continue retrying for 10 seconds if a `EBUSY`, `ENOTEMPTY`, or `EPERM` error code is encountered when trying to clean up the directory
3. Running `app.exit()` before the `rimraf(myLocalAppData)`

I know the NSIS installer provided by [electron-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder) properly cleans up the app data directory, but I cannot use it as I need a MSI to support machine wide installations via Group Policy Management.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @Ravi I ended up using the NSIS installer. For the MSI build we just wrapped the generated NSIS exe in an msi using https://github.com/pennmanor/wix-wrapper